# Keep room door partially open at night, allowing air flow but prevent anyone from entering?

Tags: door, security

I want to keep my room door partially open so that air can flow easily, but I don't want anyone to enter my room (peeking is fine, just prevent stealing things from my room). How can I achieve this?

Best I have thought is to use door chain, but I am not sure if given ample time, anyone can hook out the door chain from outside. Any other way?

Comment: How easily do you wake up when there is noise?  You could just put a heavy object on the floor against the door.  Opening the door further will push the object, making noise to wake you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to sleep in a room while door is slightly open where there are many risks walking in front of your door. I will probably do two things

1- Lift my door a little bit more by using Door hinges so air flow can be done behind my door. 
[image]

If this is impossible here is your 2nd option:

2-You may buy a door stooper which can make sound for unwanted visitors.
[image]

Comment: Door stopper with alarm. Perfect!

Comment: That door stopper seems easier to remove than a door chain.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I think the point of it is that you'll wake up.

Comment: @crdx to me it looks like you just move it aside and open the door and it will ring only if you push the door onto it. But if the door is open a little, just put your hand through and remove it.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Put it near the hinge. Also, they'll only remove it if they know in advance that it's there.

Comment: I believe decrease in pressure will also ring the sensor? Is it not the case?

Answer (score 3):

There are several kinds of hardware for sale for just this.
Which are available where you live depends on the local market, so likely the ones I find on internet round here might be available where you live.

The most common types are meant to allow you to open the door a bit, have a look on who is there and then close the door, open the safety device and open the door fully. Most do not allow the door to open once the security closure is active, not even when you use a smart method.

The chain I had on my door in my last house not only needed the door to be 95% closed, it also needed you to press a small thingy while taking the chain out, so it was impossible to open the door unless you were actually inside.
[This is one of them.](http://www.groetenuitsurduk.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Balkondeurantiboevensluiting_web.jpg)

If you use any of those methods that prevents the door to be opened without the person inside changing something, you will have to keep the door open while the device is active. Those do not keep the door open.
In fact the device in the picture I linked to above was in a story about it getting locked on closure of the door by accident, [(Dutch language story)](http://www.groetenuitsurduk.nl/?p=10563)

There is also hardware that is designed to hold doors or windows on a tiny gap for a long time, mostly used on doors that are not the main entrance to a house or room, but they might work for you.
Those should also be available for doors open in as well as out, as both methods of opening garden doors and windows can be common.
A [clamp like this (from a commercial site](https://static.karwei.nl/mam/celum/celum_assets/8864772390942_8713249223278_1_95992_tif_picture_220Wx220H.jpg)) is combined with a metal plate with two or three slots. The slots are such that one closes the door, the other one or two allow the door to be kept open a little bit.
Where these items used to be common here, the local stores do not sell them anymore, likely because most doors and windows have been replaced by plastic ones.

Comment: What is your suggestion? You keep saying *"there is hardware / there are methods"* but fail to name or talk about what those solutions actually are. (the author already mentioned the chain)

Comment: It did cost time to find photos from other than commercial sites.

Comment: Still looking for other kinds

Comment: @Willeke I know that the chains are risky cause you can open them from outside easily all you need a balloon or a thick  paper. But I have a metal piece mounted inside my door and wall and it works like a chain and locked from inside my door and only way to pass it is breaking my door. I could not find the link but if I find it I will share here for you.

Comment: @melic Door chains come in many different versions and most you can not easily open without closing the door.

Comment: @Willeke what I know about thiefs and locks; there is no lock for them.Once I got caught a thief in my bedroom but they escaped.And Police told me that I was lucky.So if you ask me it is best to make some noise will push them to escape that is why I am always saying people to put some devices making noises.And about chains everything in hand against them counts even fake cameras.

Answer (score 1):

Keep room door partially open at night, allowing air flow but prevent anyone from entering?
Here is what you can do.

[image]

The thing which prevents the door from opening completely is known as ***Door Chain***.
As you can see it provides you some space for air and definitely no person can enter your room.

I hoped I helped.

image source: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjg8cfsjr3TAhXIMI8KHQNWDh4QjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fartanzania.com%2Fmodern%2Fdoor-chain-locks.html&psig=AFQjCNEc-aZvsEIZlZSAP8yR8CBsv2JtkA&ust=1493124061521029

Comment: Thanks Nisarg, but as I said in my question, I thought about door chains but I am not sure if given ample time anyone can unhook the door chain from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a trap that is triggered when the door opens. One simple option would be leaning a broom or some similar pole against the inside of the door. If someone opens the door, the broom will fall and smack down on the floor, waking you up. You'd have to prop the door open a few inches with something, like a shoe, or else the weight of the broom might push it closed.

You could also create a "tripping hazard" just inside your room, by placing marbles, low furniture, beer bottles, etc. on the floor.

Comment: Nice hack! I can use door stopper to keep the door in place and place some thing that will create noise if it falls down.

Answer (score 0):

Install a louver door which will let the air in but not people. Better yet, create a louvered section for the door which can be removed and replaced with a solid piece, when you want complete privacy from people as well as air.

Answer (score -2):

For fire safety, *please* keep your door completely closed.  That way, if there's a fire in your house, you'll have the door keeping smoke away from you for long enough to make your escape (or at least call emergency services).  In fact, keep *all* your doors closed when you sleep; doing so slows the spread of a fire, if one should occur.

If you live alone, someone in your flat while you sleep has already *broken into your house* and a door chain, alarm wedge, or *Home Alone* style booby trap won't keep them out of your bedroom if they decide to turn simple burglary into a home invasion.

If you want/need ventilation at night, open a window.  If it's too hot outside (summer's coming, after all), small window air conditioners are under $100 new and require only basic home tools and skills to install.

Comment: I live alone in a flat with several rooms. I never feel the need to keep all doors completely closed, and looking around and talking with others here it is common to keep doors within the house open at night.

Comment: Anyone who deals in fire safety will disagree with that.  If there's a fire in your flat, a closed door could save your life by preventing smoke and gas from overcoming you before you can wake up enough to react.  All doors should be closed when you sleep.

Comment: Hi Zeiss, thanks for taking time out, but sorry to say this answer feels irrelevant to me.

Comment: If you feel a warning (that what you want to accomplish is unsafe) is irrelevant, that's your choice.  I just think sleeping with your door open is a bad idea -- and if you live alone, someone walking into your bedroom while you sleep presumes they've already broken into your house, and nothing here is likely to stop them if they decide to turn simple burglary into home invasion.